# The CPU load is varying considerably for same UPD traffic on the GCP VMs of same machine type

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are facing an issue with GCP VMs,  though the machine type is same, the CPU load is varying considerably for same UDP traffic on the VMs

```
**stress-ng --taskset 1 --udp 1 --udp-ops 20000000 --metrics-brief**
```

•       On stress test with 20M –udp-ops,  instance A consumed 84 seconds and instance B consumed 92 seconds (CPU load is same on both)

```
**taskset -c 1 iperf3 -c 10.79.0.114 -u -n 200M -b 40M -l 32B**
```

•       When run iperf tool with UDP traffic, instance A consumed 33% CPU and instance B consumed 47% CPU.

```
**taskset -c 1 iperf3 -c 10.79.0.114  -n 200M -b 40M -l 32B**
```

•       But, iperf with TCP traffic show same equal CPU load on both the VMs

If we do stop and start these VMs from console we are not seeing this issue sometimes. We are suspecting some hypervisor/network/Host issue, could you suggest?

Comment: Was the traffic rate indeed equal between the two iperf tests?  (As an aside, the second command line does not include the -u option - was that merely a transcription error?)
My recollection is iperf uses getrusage() to gather CPU utilization figures.  That will be strictly CPU time charged directly to the process.  While you have bound the processes to the same CPU (at least the iperf3 client) you have not fully-specified the four-tuple of the traffic, so which vCPU will be taking interrupts can change from run to run.

Comment: No, first iperf run with UDP and second is with TCP (no -u option).
Server IP : 10.79.0.114
Client1 IP: 10.79.0.111
Client2 IP: 10.79.0.112

The above figures were consistent with multiple runs